# Issue with updating only the selected form data in React and Tailwind

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project using React and Tailwind CSS, where I have a form. When I click the "Save" button, the form data is displayed in a div. Then, when I click on that div, a modal opens for updating the data. However, I noticed that when I update one entry, all the entries get updated. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

```
export default function LaborantModal() {
  // Relevant context and state declarations...

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const laborantEvent = {
      name,
      surname,
      inputValue,
    };

    if (selectedEvent) {
      dispatchCalEvent({ type: 'update', payload: laborantEvent });
    } else {
      dispatchCalEvent({ type: 'push', payload: laborantEvent });
    }

    setShowLaborantModal(false);
  }

function savedEventsReducer(state, {type, payload}){
  switch (type) {
      case 'push':
          return[...state, payload];
      case'update':
          return state.map(evt => evt.id === payload.id ? payload : evt)
      case 'delete':    
          return state.filter(evt => evt.id !== payload.id)
      default:
          throw new Error();
  }
}

 <div className='mb-1'>
        <AddLaborantButton/>
        <div 
          className='py-5'
          onClick={()=>{
                setShowLaborantModal(true)
              }}>
                {savedEvents.map((evt, idx) => (
                <div
                key={idx}
                onClick={()=> setSelectedEvent(evt)}
                className={ 'bg-purple-400 p-1 mr-3 py-2 text-white text-sm rounded mb-5 truncate'}>
                    {evt.name}
                </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
```